# Store any character from ASCII table from 0 - 255 into MySQL VARCHAR(22)?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, collation, varchar

I concatenated a String of 21 ASCII chars (which can be any ASCII character from 0 - 255) and I'm trying to store this String into a VARCHAR in MySQL database table.
However, it seems to not store properly into the database -- sometimes the String is too long somehow, or when it's not too long and I read it back, it gives me the wrong characters.

What is the collation/configurations that will allow me to do this? I'm using PHP as the programming language, and I'm running on a Linux server through PuTTy.

Schema for table:

```
ID ...
FirstName ... 
LastName ... 
Email ...
HoursRange | varchar(22) | YES | | NULL | |
```

Php code:
($hoursRange is a string of 168 bits, which I convert to a String of 21 chars)

```
$toBytes = "";
for($i = 0; $i < 168; $i+=8){
    $decVal = bindec(substr($hoursRange, $i, $i+8)); // this becomes decimal
    $toBytes = $toBytes . chr($decVal);
}
```

Then I store it into the database:

```
$notice->addSubscriber($firstName, $lastName, $email, $toBytes);
```

Add subscriber (function takes in 4 parameters):

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Subscribers (FirstName, LastName, Email, HoursRange) VALUES(:fname, :lname, :email, :hoursRange)");
$stmt->bindparam(":fname", $FirstName);
$stmt->bindparam(":lname", $LastName);
$stmt->bindparam(":email", $Email);
$stmt->bindparam(":hoursRange", $hoursRange);

$stmt->execute();
return $stmt;
```

Comment: If you show us some code and maybe the schema for the database table, we could be of more help

Comment: You definitely have to set the correct charset for the connection (something you do in PHP)

Comment: What would the charset be? I set it to utf8 but no-go.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BINARY(21)`, not any form of `CHAR`.  And a good way to do the `INSERT` is `UNHEX('...')`.  Similarly `SELECT HEX(...)` can be handy.  Also `0b'...'` would let you use a string of 0s and 1s instead of hex.

ASCII is only 0..127.  Fix your question.

Without seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, it is hard for us to judge what the problem is.  If the column in question is `CHARACTER SET ascii`, then you nasty things will happen to the outer 128 values when you try to store them.

For `CHARACTER SET latin1`, it might pass OK.

`utf8` and `utf8mb4` are very likely to croak at your values.

Maybe you want `VARBINARY` or `BLOB`?  Those have no concept of character set; it's just 8-bit bytes.